# jQuery radio button on change function runs twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this little function in my website:

```
$( 'form .radio_buttons' ).change( doTheFunction )
```

which works fine, but I noticed that it is always running twice whenever a radio button option changes. After thinking for 5 seconds I realized what was going on; there are 2 change events occurring:

```
change 1: the checked radio button is unchecked 
change 2: the unchecked radio button is checked
```

My question is how do I treat this as one event? is there a slick Javascript function I can use?

EDIT: 
It seems there may be a deeper issue going on here, I can't duplicate the problem outside of my app, but Scott Marcus' answer worked for me. I'll have to figure out why change events are firing twice...

Comment: Try this $('form .radio_buttons').off('change').on('change', doTheFunction())

Comment: And there might be a possibility that your script is executing twice.

Comment: Take the `()` off of the function you are passing in as the event handler.  This is causing it to fire immediately.  Unless you actually want that to happen.

Comment: You should create a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: @taplar removed `()` still runs the function twice

Comment: When are you creating that binding?  Something is fishy here.

Comment: can you post your html ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gbtq2wc5/  The change event only runs once per change.  If it is running multiple times, this is an indicator of double binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really shouldn't be happening and without your code we really can't say for sure what the issue is, but rather than working with the `change` event, you can use the `click` event.

It may be that there is other code in your application that causes your `change` callback to be firing twice.

Comment: If you look at the fiddle in the comments, 2 change events do not happen.

Comment: While that might be good advise it is not why OP is having this issue. Changing it to click works around the problem and ignores the actual reason OP is having the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('[name=myradio]').change(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    alert('checked : '+ $(this).val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<label><input type="radio" name="myradio" value="radio1">radio 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="myradio" value="radio2">radio 2</label>
```